# Start AsyncTask inside of a Thread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to start a simple process of getting the HTML code of a webpage from inside an AsyncTask, because when it's from the new Thread the UI freezes for few moments, how can I do it?

```
public void loadHTML(View vL) {
    final String ss = (et.getText().toString());

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(ss));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    final String responseString = out.toString();
                    tvW.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvW.setText(responseString);
                        }
                    });


                    Log.v("DYRA BYRA", responseString);
                } else {
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

I want this part `tvW.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvW.setText(responseString);
                            }
                        });`

to be in AsyncTask

Comment: you can't do this ... operation on Views should be on main\UI thread ... i think that UI freezing has cause in `responseString`  length ... anyway get read of all `out` related stuff and use `responseString  = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");`

Comment: no its not a duplicate thank you very much

Comment: Create a handler for the TextView you are setting the text for and then send it a message containing the string from the Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I wanted to do

```
public void loadHTML(View vL) {
    new getCode().execute();
}

private class getCode extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        final String ss = (et.getText().toString());
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(ss));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
                Log.v("DYRA BYRA", responseString);
            } else {
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tvW.setText(responseString);
    }

}
```

the UI still freezes for like half second, but perhaps that's because the received HTML is extremely long

Answer (score 0):

Uh i don't think you need an asynctask but a run on ui thread

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
              tvW.setText(responseString);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sync your Thread with the UI-Thread. Because all UI relevant operations like writing to an TextView have to be done on the UI-Thread. Therefor you should use the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

Now replace this code:

```
tvW.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          tvW.setText(responseString);
     }
});
```

With this one:

```
 myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          tvW.setText(responseString);
     }
});
```

Note that your Handler class have to be declared on the UI-Thread to get connected.

Comment: nope, that still freezes the app for a second :(

Comment: Well, what's the length of the responseString? Selvin suggested this  already. There could be a problem too.

Comment: it's long yes, imagine a whole HTML code from a webpage... the thing is, I MUST do it somehow with asynctask

Comment: There is your problem.. It doesn't matter if you use a Thread/Handler combination or AsyncTask. At the point of setting the text to the View both working quite the same way. Like Selvin said, reduce/modify the String before you set it.